# Reading CAN bus in C displays incorrect CAN ID for 29-bit CAN ID

Tags: c, linux, can-bus

I wrote some code in C to read CAN bus data. Everything works correctly when I read 11-bit CAN IDs. As soon as I try to read 29-bit IDs it displays the ID incorrectly.

**Example:**

Receiving message with 29-bit ID:

**0x01F0A020**

And print it with

```
printf("%X\n", frame.can_id);
```

it prints **81F0A020**.

11-bit ID message

**0x7DF**

and print it with

```
printf("%X\n", frame.can_id);
```

It prints correctly **7DF**.

Why is this the case?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/raw.h>

#define MAX_DATA_LEN 8
#define MAX_FIELDS 23
#define MAX_FIELD_LEN 64
#include <limits.h>

char data_str[MAX_FIELDS][MAX_FIELD_LEN];
int i;

int
main(void)
{
    int s;
    int nbytes;
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct can_frame frame;
    unsigned short data[MAX_FIELDS];
    int sockfd = 0;
    int bcast = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in dst_addr;
    int numbytes;

    int fa;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    fa = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);

    ioctl(fa, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
    close(fa);

    //
    if((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Udp sockfd create failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Enabled broadcast mode for udp
    if((setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,
                &bcast, sizeof bcast)) == -1)
    {
        perror("setsockopt failed for broadcast mode ");
        exit(1);
    }

    src_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    src_addr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    src_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(src_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof src_addr.sin_zero);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &src_addr, sizeof src_addr) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    dst_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dst_addr.sin_port = htons(45454);
    dst_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    memset(dst_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof dst_addr.sin_zero);

    if((s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0) {
        perror("Error while opening socket");
        return -1;
    }

    addr.can_family  = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = 0;

    if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error in socket bind");
        return -2;
    }

    //struct can_frame frame;
    while(1)
    {
        nbytes = read(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));

        if (nbytes < 0) {
                perror("can raw socket read");
                return 1;
        }

        /* Paranoid check ... */
        if (nbytes < sizeof(struct can_frame)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read: incomplete CAN frame\n");
                return 1;
        }

        // Print the received CAN ID
        printf("%X\n", frame.can_id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the fishy `(struct sockaddr*)` casts?

Comment: @Bodo Casting between different struct types invokes undefined behavior and may very well be a bug. Are they truly compatible types? If so, why use two different types. It is either code smell or library smell.

Comment: Peeked at the Github. `struct sockaddr` in sys/socket.h is not in the slightest compatible with `struct sockaddr_can`, so it appears to be a library bug. They are non-compatible types and it is also a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @Bodo The only thing that matters is if the struct is de-referenced as `struct sockaddr` anywhere - if so it is a bug. Otherwise it is just muddy API design.

Comment: @Bodo The thing is, they can't check the initial element unless it is of the same lvalue type as the whole of `struct sockaddr_can`, which it isn't. At worst, you get misaligned access. At best, you get an open invitation for gcc optimizer to go bananas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199610/discussion-between-bodo-and-lundin).

Comment: @Lundin I remove all my comments which are now in the chat because the discussion about the socket interface design is only remotely related to the question. I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field `can_id` of `struct can_frame` contains the CAN ID **and** the EFF/RTR/ERR flags. The extended ID has 29 bits, so there are 3 free bits that are used to represent 3 flags.

Your example ID `0x01F0A020` must be an extended frame, but ID `0x7DF` can be sent as a base frame or as an extended frame. These are different messages. To distinguish between a base frame or an extended frame with the same ID you need the EFF flag.

In your example you see the value `0x81F0A020` which is the combination of ID `0x01F0A020` and `CAN_EFF_FLAG` (`0x80000000U`).

**Extract from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/can.h**

```
/* special address description flags for the CAN_ID */
#define CAN_EFF_FLAG 0x80000000U /* EFF/SFF is set in the MSB */
#define CAN_RTR_FLAG 0x40000000U /* remote transmission request */
#define CAN_ERR_FLAG 0x20000000U /* error message frame */

/* valid bits in CAN ID for frame formats */
#define CAN_SFF_MASK 0x000007FFU /* standard frame format (SFF) */
#define CAN_EFF_MASK 0x1FFFFFFFU /* extended frame format (EFF) */
#define CAN_ERR_MASK 0x1FFFFFFFU /* omit EFF, RTR, ERR flags */
```

...

```
/**
 * struct can_frame - basic CAN frame structure
 * @can_id:  CAN ID of the frame and CAN_*_FLAG flags, see canid_t definition
 * @can_dlc: frame payload length in byte (0 .. 8) aka data length code
 *           N.B. the DLC field from ISO 11898-1 Chapter 8.4.2.3 has a 1:1
 *           mapping of the 'data length code' to the real payload length
 * @__pad:   padding
 * @__res0:  reserved / padding
 * @__res1:  reserved / padding
 * @data:    CAN frame payload (up to 8 byte)
 */
struct can_frame {
    canid_t can_id;  /* 32 bit CAN_ID + EFF/RTR/ERR flags */
    __u8    can_dlc; /* frame payload length in byte (0 .. CAN_MAX_DLEN) */
    __u8    __pad;   /* padding */
    __u8    __res0;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    __res1;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    data[CAN_MAX_DLEN] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

To get the ID only without flags, you should apply `CAN_SFF_MASK` or `CAN_EFF_MASK` depending on the value of the `CAN_EFF_FLAG` bit.

**Example code:**

```
        //Print the received CAN ID 
        printf("%X\n", 
               (frame.can_id & CAN_EFF_FLAG) ? (frame.can_id & CAN_EFF_MASK)
                                             : (frame.can_id & CAN_SFF_MASK));
```

Comment: Is the combination done on the ID and flag an OR `|` or an XOR `^`? In the example, there are the flag: `0x80000000` (`10000000000000000000000000000000`) , the ID: `0x01F0A020` (`00000001111100001010000000100000`) and the result `0x81F0A020` (`10000001111100001010000000100000`). The result can be obtained both from OR and XOR.

Comment: @wr43th13 Your question is about basic bit operations. If you want to make sure a bit is set, use `value | bit`, if you want to make sure the bit is not set use `value & (~bit)`. Use unsignet types of the same width to avoid possibly wrong type conversion. Using XOR means inverting a bit. This works only if you are sure the bit you want to set is not already set. That means if you repeat the operation `value |= bit` the value will not change, if you repeat `value ^= bit` you will toggle the bit with every operation.